Apps Script: need to track the sheet where change occurred using onChange
I have a script autoupdating cols A-D in specific sheet, from onChange trigger. The problem is, when user manipulates data in some of these cols, autoupdate is unneeded.
It seemed that easy solution would be to block autoupdate if onchange event originated from these cols, but so far don't see how to implement this, as there's no e.range object in onChange. Would appreciate any ideas.

I don't remember what the event object looks like for an onChange because I hardly ever use them.  Can you capture the event object and post it here
